# Fill in missing values for missing dates in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have the following dataframe:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'status': ['open', 'closed', 'open', 'closed', 'open', 'closed', 'open', 'closed'],
        'month': ['January 2020', 'January 2020', 'February 2020', 'February 2020', 'April 2020', 'April 2020', 'August 2020', 'August 2020'],
        'counts': [10, 12, 32, 12, 19, 40, 10, 11]
    }
)
```

```
    status  month           counts
0   open    January 2020    10
1   closed  January 2020    12
2   open    February 2020   32
3   closed  February 2020   12
4   open    April 2020      19
5   closed  April 2020      40
6   open    August 2020     10
7   closed  August 2020     11
```

I'm trying to get a stacked bar plot using seaborn:

```py
sns.histplot(df, x='month', weights='counts', hue='status', multiple='stack')
```

[image]

The purpose is to get a plot with a continuous timeseries without missing months. How can I fill in the missing rows with values so that the dataframe would look like below?

```
status  month           counts
open    January 2020    10
closed  January 2020    12
open    February 2020   32
closed  February 2020   12
open    March 2020      0
closed  March 2020      0
open    April 2020      19
closed  April 2020      40
open    May 2020        0
closed  May 2020        0
open    June 2020       0
closed  June 2020       0
open    July 2020       0
closed  July 2020       0
open    August 2020     10
closed  August 2020     11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pivot the dataframe, and then reindex with the desired months.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'status': ['open', 'closed', 'open', 'closed', 'open', 'closed', 'open', 'closed'],
                   'month': ['January 2020', 'January 2020', 'February 2020', 'February 2020', 'April 2020', 'April 2020', 'August 2020', 'August 2020'],
                   'counts': [10, 12, 32, 12, 19, 40, 10, 11]})

months = [f'{m} 2020' for m in ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August']]
df_pivoted = df.pivot(values='counts', index='month', columns='status').reindex(months).fillna(0)
ax = df_pivoted.plot.bar(stacked=True, width=1, ec='black', rot=0, figsize=(12, 5))
```

[image: pandas bar plot using pivoted dataframe]

A seaborn solution, could use `order=`. That doesn't work with a `histplot`, only with a `barplot`, which doesn't stack bars.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'status': ['open', 'closed', 'open', 'closed', 'open', 'closed', 'open', 'closed'],
                   'month': ['January 2020', 'January 2020', 'February 2020', 'February 2020', 'April 2020', 'April 2020', 'August 2020', 'August 2020'],
                   'counts': [10, 12, 32, 12, 19, 40, 10, 11]})

plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
months = [f'{m} 2020' for m in ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August']]
ax = sns.barplot(data=df, x='month', y='counts', hue='status', order=months)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.barplot]

Comment: Thank you. Pivoting the dataframe seems to work best in my case. I haven't specified in the question, but the dataframe includes multiple years, so I used  pd.date_range(start=min(df['months']), end=max(df['months']), freq='MS').strftime('%B %Y').tolist() to get the list of all months.